# Python wont recognize the end of a word in if-else statement?

Tags: python, computer-science

So I'm trying to design a function where if the first and last letter of a string are the same, it returns true but otherwise return false.

Here is my code so far

```
def same_first_and_last_letter(str):
if s[0] == s[–1]:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I get an error called `SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier`
Why is this happening? I thought the if statements evaluate if each side of the == side is true ?

Edit: The full error is

```
File "<ipython-input-54-897fe4b51e80>", line 2
    if s[0] == s[–1]:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: First problem I see is wrong indentation. Try moving everything after the function definition 4-spaces in.

Comment: Second would be function argument being `str` and `s` being actually used.

Comment: these two comments are the RC for your issue. Nothing else in this 4 liner to fix.

Comment: @tvm, function argument "str" is not a problem, python can handle that.. and if s is defined before the function then that is not a problem either. (but you are probably right that he meant to take s: str as argument).

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @MartinSo: Don't correct your code. That's what answers are for. Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Ok, now we can see what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, now from your error traceback:

```py
File "<ipython-input-54-897fe4b51e80>", line 2
    if s[0] == s[–1]:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Python is indicating the `1` is wrong, but what it is really pointing out is that the `-` is wrong.

Compare these:

```py
s[–1]
s[-1]
```

Can you see it? Its very difficult to see.

The first line has an `–` which is not `-`. I don't know what you typed but its not the negative or minus char.

It seems to be unicode `8211` if anyone can identify this.

Comment: Wow okay, Looks like python is really strict on the syntax. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

```py
def same_first_and_last_letter(s):
  
  if s[0] == s[::-1][0]: # s[::-1] reverse the string and 0 uses 1st index of reversed string
    return True
  else:
    return False

same_first_and_last_letter("HelloH")
```

Output:

```
True
```

Indentation and s is what you are missing

Comment: It still gets the same  error

Comment: Please stop this. Did you even try your code?

Comment: @MartinSo: And where is the full error traceback I requested?

Comment: @MartinSo Please check my updated answer

Comment: Look at the accepted answer.  Think about the complexity of yours...reversing the string just so that you don't have to reference the last character rather than the first of a string?  Your answer a step backwards.  The clear answer was the one accepted...to show the OP that they had used the wrong character for negation.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the reply. You are right as I was only thinking about solving the answer but did not actually thought about complexity.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are good, try to do it in one line since the code isn't complicated

```
def same_first_and_last_letter(s):
    return s[0] == s[-1]
```

Comment: Please stop this. Did you even try your code?

Comment: @quamrana not sure why `-` didnt appear as I expected, lol,,thanks for correcting

Comment: Ok, you found it! Well done. But now you need to explain this to the OP. Without correcting their post by editing it.